# Binance API, simple GET price by ticker, not working

Tags: api, binance

When I excute this code as Google Sheets Script, my first and subsequent attempts rarely retrieves the data from Binance. Occasionally it will work. Can anyone help?

```
function BINTickFetch(){
  var rows=[],obj_array=null;
  try {obj_array=JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price").getContentText());} catch (e) {obj_array=null;}
  if (obj_array==null) {
    Browser.msgBox("data not received from Binance. Try again"); 
    return false;
  }
  else {
    for (r in obj_array) rows.push([obj_array[r].symbol, parseFloat(obj_array[r].price)]);
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),sheet=ss.getSheetByName('Binance24h');ss.getRange("Binance24h!A1").setValue(new Date());
    try {var range=sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow(),2).clearContent();} catch(e) {Logger.log("error");}
    if (rows==null) {Browser.msgBox("incomplete symbol data from Binance. Try again"); return false;}
    range=sheet.getRange(2,1,rows.length,2); range.setValues(rows); 
  }
}
```

(got the code off the internet somewhere)

Comment: Please check here [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with that site and I use Yahoo finance. This will grab historical pricing for MSFT

```
function importCSVFromWeb() {
  // Provide the full URL of the CSV file.
  var csvUrl = "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/MSFT?period1=1577806579&period2=1609428979&interval=1d&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true";
  var csvContent = UrlFetchApp.fetch(csvUrl).getContentText();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvContent);

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
}
```

Yahoo uses unix date stamps for the beginning and ending periods

This is one way to convert dates to unix date stamps

```
function getUnixDateStamp(stdDate){
strDate = stdDate.yyyymmdd();
return Date.parse(strDate)/1000
}
```

Comment: Excellent. could you point to Yahoo Finance API Docs?

Comment: I'd like to request a list

Comment: I am not sure Yahoo publishes an official API, I believe there is a 3rd party company that offers a product. But I just use a simple web request as you see above. To get the URL I just visited the site, typed in a stock symbol and then went to Historical Data and then copied the link for Download.

Comment: also found that api1.binance.com (instead of api.binance.com) appears to cure the problem for now at least.